# Codeigniter 404 issue phpstorm

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, phpstorm

I'm new to Codeigniter and i followed instructions on http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html . I created project with PhpStorm 9.0 and try to launch index.php file and it works, but  when I try to launch new controller "blog" http://localhost:63342/site.ru/blog/, occurs 404 error. I'm using Linux Mint 17 and LAMP. Php 5.5.9,apache 2.4.

So project located in default Phpstorm directory ~/PhpstormProjects/site.ru/ 
Here is my config settings

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:63342/site.ru/';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

And my blog.php file consists

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
   echo "Hello, World!";
}
}
```

PhpStorm using built-in web server so it adds port 63342 to localhost.
I've been searching solution in internet but nothing helps me.
I tried add .htaccess file to controllers folder, but it didnt help me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

And here is routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: **1)** You are not using Apache from your LAMP -- you are using PhpStorm's **simple** built-in server **2)** PhpStorm's server does NOT support mod_rewrite instructions (RewriteRule and similar) -- it (basically) works with exact file names.

Comment: Go to Settings, look for Deployments; then create & configure deployment entry (that's where you specify your LAMP URL that will be used). Do not forget to mark this deployment entry as Default for this project. Now IDE will use that URL when you use `Open in Browser` action. If such entry is not defined, then PhpStorm uses it's own server. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm

Comment: Because you have not removed index.php on config.php and with a htaccess I think you should have index.php in url `http://localhost:63342/site.ru/index.php/blog/` If your using codeigniter 3 make sure first letter of filename and class name upper case Blog.php

Comment: LazyOne, I did it! The solution you suggested me helped me. I had incorrect local web server settings in PhpStorm Deployment settings, I've changed it and created virtual host to launch my site from /home/ directory.
The problem was that I set deployment server 'In place' instead of 'local or mounted folder'. Thank you very much!

Comment: wolfgang1983, I did the same what in official tutorial and in my case it didnt work, but i found root of my problem. I tried to add index.php to url but it didnt helped me.